git diff-tree only returning high level directories in the commit
I'm trying to get all the file names changed in a git commit using git diff-tree:
git diff-tree --diff-filter=* --no-commit-id --name-only -r "${GIT_COMMIT}" *
But I only get the high level directories in the commit.

Found out that the issue is that it's a delete operation. So git only reports the folder that is being deleted, not the contents.
